# useEffect with useState not rerendering React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component where the user drags some files and stores it in a state. Without getting into the bulk of the code, here is what I have

```
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFiles(getFileList(files, acceptedFiles));
  }, [files, acceptedFiles]);
```

I am using the [React Dropzone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone) package and when the user drops files to the container, the *acceptedFiles* property of dropzone gets populated with those files. In the useEffect hook, I want to set my state *files* based on these new files i.e. whenever the user adds new files, I want to update my state to include these new files and trigger a rerender. However, this isn't happening. When I drop a file, nothing gets rendered. But then when I drop another file, the first file gets rendered and when I add a third file, the second gets rendered and so on... I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any advice?

Here is my component:

```
export function Upload() {
  const { acceptedFiles, getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive, open } =
    useDropzone({ noClick: true });

  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFiles(getFileList(files, acceptedFiles));
  }, [files, acceptedFiles]);

  const baseContent = (
    <div className={styles.baseContent}>
      <h4 className={styles.uploadText}>{"click to add or drop files here"}</h4>
      <AiOutlineUpload className={styles.icon} />
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <Dropzone getRootProps={getRootProps} isDragActive={isDragActive}>
      {files.length === 0 ? (
        <Clickzone getInputProps={getInputProps} open={open}>
          {baseContent}
        </Clickzone>
      ) : (
        <FileSystem files={files} getInputProps={getInputProps} open={open} />
      )}
    </Dropzone>
  );
}

function getFileList(files, newFiles) {
  var totalSize = getTotalSize(files);
  var count = files.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < newFiles.length; i++) {
    if (count >= constants.MAX_NUM_OF_FILES) break;

    var file = {
      name: newFiles[i].name,
      type: newFiles[i].type,
      size: newFiles[i].size,
    };

    file.name = sanitizeFileName(file.name);
    file.size = convertToMB(file.size);

    if (file.size > constants.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE) continue;
    totalSize += file.size;
    if (totalSize > constants.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE) break;
    count++;
    files.push(file);
  }

  return files;
}
```

Comment: Where is `acceptedFiles` defined?

Comment: Can you include some more of your code. I know React-Dropzone also has some great docs so I imagine your answer is in there

Comment: @Phil, acceptedFiles is part of react-dropzone. When the user adds a file, acceptedFiles gets populated.

Comment: @RichardHpa, I added some more code for reference. I looked through the documentation but I couldn't find anything related to what I want to accomplish, though I'm still new so maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 1):

At the moment your useEffect is waiting for files and accepted files to run. This would actually cause an infinite loop since you changing files would cause the useEffect to run which then sets files.

What you should be doing is using the onDrop event and call the function once files have been dropped.

So something like this

```js
export function Upload() {
  const { acceptedFiles, getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive, open } =
    useDropzone({ noClick: true });

  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  const baseContent = (
    <div className={styles.baseContent}>
      <h4 className={styles.uploadText}>{"click to add or drop files here"}</h4>
      <AiOutlineUpload className={styles.icon} />
    </div>
  );

  const onDropAccepted = (acceptedFiles) => {
    setFiles(acceptedFiles)
  }

  return (
    <Dropzone getRootProps={getRootProps} isDragActive={isDragActive} onDrop={handleInDropAccepted}>
      {files.length === 0 ? (
        <Clickzone getInputProps={getInputProps} open={open}>
          {baseContent}
        </Clickzone>
      ) : (
        <FileSystem files={files} getInputProps={getInputProps} open={open} />
      )}
    </Dropzone>
  );
}
```

Here is a link to the docs which shows you all of the other props you can add in, https://react-dropzone.js.org/#!/Dropzone